# Perl SFTP download oldest files first

Tags: perl

I am having an issue where I am trying to download the oldest files first and the directory listing isn't coming back correctly. The example below is how I thought it should be done but I cant get it to work. I am using the Net::SFTP::Foreign module.

```
$source_sftp->setcwd($path) or die "unable to change cwd: " . $source_sftp->error;

my @ls = @{ $source_sftp->ls ('.', names_only => 1,
                                no_wanted => qr/^\./,
                                )};

my @sorted = sort { $a->{a}{mtime} <=> $b->{a}{mtime} } $@ls;

for (@sorted) {

print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After going through [`Net::SFTP::Foreign`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.81/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm), I believe , you are doing two mistakes:

First, you are retrieving only names of file with `names_only => 1`. So you will not get `mtime`.

Second, I am not sure what you are doing with `$@ls` dereferencing array into scalar. It is `syntax error`.

All you need to do is perform simple `$sftp -> ls(...)` and get `mtime` from `Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes` object in the result and `sort` it.

Below two lines will work for you:

```
my @ls =  @{ $sftp -> ls('.', no_wanted => qr/^\./)   
               or die "unable to retrieve directory: ".$sftp -> error };

my @sorted = map{$_ -> {filename}}
             sort{ $a -> {a}{mtime} <=> $b -> {a}{mtime} } 
             @ls;
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed thank you very much for the explanation.